Why does assigning different object keys in JavaScript result in the same value?
I've come across the following code snippet in JavaScript and I'm having trouble understanding exactly what's going on:


const a = {};
const b = {
  key: 'b'
};
const c = {
  key: 'c'
};

a[b] = 123;
a[c] = 456;

console.log(a[b]);



I expected a[b] to output 123, but instead, it returns 456. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Object keys are strings, so when you assign an object as a key, JS attempts to stringify it, which results in "[object Object]" for both b and c. Log the object keys to see. Log the a after assigning each value.

Ah so if i understand correctly, a["[object Object]"] would return 456?

Yes, because the output of a.toString() and b.toString() is [object Object], so your second call to set the value in a[] is overwiting the first one as the keys are duplicated. Use a[b.key] = 123; a[c.key] = 456; instead

You could also use console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 2)) to view what a looks like to the browser. There you would find it would output { "[object Object]": 456 }
